# Is 'isArraylike'?

Tags: javascript, arrays

As for my understanding 'ArrayLike' type in JavaScript is an object with *own* numeric positive integer keys, not necesary in successive order(sparse arrays etc.), where object's (int) `.length` property is greater of them all, right? I came across dozen of explanations of the thing but every one of them gave diferent point of view, so I've wrote the function that finds max (int) key, trashes `.length` property (to prevent `Math.max()` yielding `NaN` value, wich compares `false` to anything) leaving the rest of object's own keys intact. If all of them are numerics it gives back max one, if not it gives `NaN`(returning `false` as result), and compared it's outputs with accepted jQuery equivalent function's results on same values. All explanations are welcome. Here's the code I've ran:

```
// /jQuery version
function isArraylike(obj) {

  // casted the obj parameter to Object here 
  // because some primitive values was throwing an error 
  // not supporting .property access or 'in' operand
  // it doesn't change the logic just converts them to equivalent wrapped types

  var length = (obj = Object(obj)).length,
    type = jQuery.type(obj);

  if (type === "function" || jQuery.isWindow(obj)) {
    return false;
  }

  if (obj.nodeType === 1 && length) {
    return true;
  }

  return type === "array" || length === 0 ||
    typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && (length - 1) in obj;
}

// and my version
function isalike(o) {

  try {

    o.length;

    return (Math.max.apply(Math,
      erase(Object.keys(o), "length")
    ) < o.length);

  } catch (e) {}

  return false;

  function erase(arr, val) {
    var idx;
    ((idx = arr.indexOf(val)) != -1) && arr.splice(idx, 1);
    return arr;
  }

  function s(arg) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arg, 0);
  }

}

// and tests cases that came to my mind
// first boolean value in side comment is jq's output
// second is '.isalike()' function's output
var a = 
{
  0: [], // #0 true true
  1: new Array, // #1 true true
  2: new Array(10), // #2 true true
  3: {}, // #3 false false
  4: {length:0}, // #4 true true
  5: {length:"0"}, // #5 false true
  6: {length:"asd"}, // #6 false false
  7: {length:false}, // #7 false true
  8: {length:true}, // #8 false true
  9: {length:null}, // #9 false true
 10: {length:0, 0:1}, // #10 true false
 11: {length:"0", 0:1}, // #11 false false
 12: {length:0, 1:1}, // #12 true false
 13: {length:0, 2:1}, // #13 true false
 14: {length:"asd", 0:1}, // #14 false false
 15: {length:0, x1:1}, // #15 true false
 16: {length:0, 0:1, x1:1, x2:1}, // #16 true false
 17: {length:1}, // #17 false true
 18: {length:1, 0:1}, // #18 true true
 19: {length:1, 1:1}, // #19 false false
 20: {length:1, 2:1}, // #20 false false
 21: {length:1, 0:1, x1:1}, // #21 true false
 22: {length:2, 0:1}, // #22 false true
 23: {length:2, 1:1}, // #23 true true
 24: {length:2, 2:1}, // #24 false false
 25: {length:2, 3:1}, // #25 false false
 26: {length:2, 1:1, x1:1}, // #26 true false
 27: window, // #27 false false
 28: document, // #28 false false
 29: function (x1) {}, // #29 false true
 30: document.documentElement, // #30 false false
 31: document.getElementsByTagName("*"), // #31 true false
 32: document.body.childNodes, // #32 true true
 33: document.body.children, // #33 true false
 34: document.querySelectorAll("*"), // #34 true true
 35: document.images, // #35 true true
 36: window.frames, // #36 false false
 37: $(), // #37 true true
 38: $("*"), // #38 true false
 39: "asd", // #39 true false
 40: {length:NaN}, // #40 false false
 41: {length:1/0} // #41 false true
};

console.clear();
for (
  var it = 0, 
  end = 42;
  it < end;
  it++
) {
  console.log( "#"+it, isArraylike(a[it]), isalike(a[it]) );
}
//
```

Comment: [Slightly old but still informative blog post from Kangax.](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I came across dozen of explanations of the thing but every one of them gave diferent point of view...

When you asked this question in 2014, there *were* different points of view. Since then, the JavaScript specification has given us a specific definition of "array-like".

The **jQuery** `isArrayLike` function, as you can see from the code, imposes lots of requirements. The object must not be a function or a Window object; it must have a `length` property; that property's value must be a number (without conversion), and it must have an element at index `length - 1`.

[**JavaScript's** definition](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-lengthofarraylike) is much less restrictive: The object must have a `length` property that doesn't throw an error when you get it and convert it to a non-negative integer with a quite loose conversion. That's it. It can be a function, a Window object, a sparse array with no element at `length - 1`, or any of several other things. All it needs is a `length` property that doesn't throw when converted. That property's value could be the string `"flibbertygibbit"` and that's fine (it'll be treated as `0`). From that link:

> **LengthOfArrayLike(*obj*)**
>
> The abstract operation LengthOfArrayLike takes argument *obj* (an Object) and returns either a normal completion containing a non-negative integer or a throw completion. It returns the value of the **"length"** property of an array-like object. It performs the following steps when called:
>
> 1. Return ℝ(? ToLength(? Get(obj, "length"))).
>
> An array-like object is any object for which this operation returns a normal completion.
>
> **NOTE 1**
>
> Typically, an array-like object would also have some properties with integer index names. However, that is not a requirement of this definition.

(In that, [ℝ](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/notational-conventions.html#%E2%84%9D) just means "the mathematical value of" (so for instance, both +0 and -0 are just 0), and [ToLength](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-tolength) is the abstract specification operation that quite loosely converts just about anything to a non-negative integer number value.)

Comment: The spec says that any object is an array-like object if the length property doesn't throw when converting to a number via the [unary + operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus). That includes functions and Safari 5.1 is one example that will use functions as array-like objects. It also includes objects with no length property and length values of NaN but personally I would not consider them array-like. I also think it's pretty safe and probably a good idea to require a length-1 property even though that isn't required in a sparse array.

Comment: @PHPGuru - Thanks for commenting. Yes, since 2014, the specification has been updated to give us a clear definition of it. I've updated the answer.